# Loop com matrizes R

Tags: r, loop, matriz

Preciso criar uma matriz que tenha todas as coordenadas referentes a uma matriz 128x128 no R

se fosse uma matriz 3x3, ex:

```
    1    2    3
1   a    b    c

2   d    e    f

3   g    h    i
```

eu precisaria da seguinte matriz

```
    x   y

1   1   1  

2   1   2

3   1   3 

4   2   1

5   2   2 

6   2   3

7   3   1

8   3   2

9   3   3
```

como posso fazer um codigo de repetição para reproduzir isso?

Comment: Como são seus dados? Precisa apenas das coordenadas da matriz (i.e., números da linha e da coluna) ou os nomes das colunas e linhas são coordenadas (p.e., coordenadas geográficas)?

Answer (score 4):

Não é necessário criar um loop para isso. A função `expand.grid` faz exatamente o que é pedido:

```
expand.grid(1:3, 1:3)
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3
8    2    3
9    3    3
```

Basta substituir 3 por 128 no código acima e tudo estará resolvido.